# Cast image to ChromeCast

Tags: casting, chromecast, google-cast

I am looking for an example of casting an image to a chrome cast from a url. There doesn't seem to be an image cast example in the google cast sample repositories but i feel this must have been done before.

I have little experience with the chrome cast sdk developer console as well as the development of the apps themselves so any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [CastHelloText-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) (or [ios](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios)) sample on out github repo. What you need to do is to use either a custom reeiver (say, start from the one used in CastHelloText) and add an image html tag and then use the cutom namespace data channel to send the url of your image to your receiver and set that as the source of your image tag. Alternatively, you can use a Styled (or the Default) receiver which supports showing images; create a MediaInfo from your image and just send load it like a video and that should work. Note that your image should be served from an accesisble web server.

Comment: Even though i want this to be done all through the chrome browser rather than on a mobile device?

Comment: Which part are you referring too? Almost all the above points apply to Chrome SDK as well.